# How to remove modifiers in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a variable `@modifier` which returns `(::22::)` now I want to remove the `:` after the value 22 i.e it should return `(::22)`. If modifier has a value of `(:10:::)`, it should return `(:10)`.

Is this possible in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Comment: Are the `()` brackets part of the values of `@modifier`? Are the only possible values digits and the `():` punctuation marks?

Comment: no () brackets are not part of the values of @modifier

Answer (score 1):

You could use of `reverse()` function

```
select @modifier [modifier],
       REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@modifier ), patindex('%[^:]%', REVERSE(@modifier )), len(@modifier))) [modifiedstring]
```

**EDIT :**

```
SELECT @modifier [modifier],
       CASE
           WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @modifier) > 0
           THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@modifier), PATINDEX('%[^:]%', REVERSE(@modifier)), LEN(@modifier)))
           ELSE ''
       END [modifiedstring];
```

**Note** : In above first you check the strings have some numeric values present or not by using `patindex()` function

Result :

```
modifier     modifiedstring
::22::       ::22
:10:::       :10
::::
```

Comment: This code works fine but when modifier only has (::::) without numbers it doesnt work. when there is no number in modifiers all the : should get deleted

Comment: @AshwanthKA you just apply case expression in above.

Comment: i dont know the use of patindex can you explain?

Comment: @AshwanthKA check here ..https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql

Comment: ok now what should i change in this code to get my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DECLARE @V VARCHAR(20) = ':10::'

SELECT
    MyString = @V,
    Result = REVERSE(
    SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@V),
                PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REVERSE(@v)),
                LEN(@V)))
```

Result

```
MyString             Result
-------------------- --------------------
:10::                :10
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. We can do this without reverse also.

```
CREATE TABLE strs1
(
    modifier VARCHAR(100)
)
Go

INSERT INTO strs1 VALUES
('::22::'),
(':10:::') 
GO


SELECT modifier,
LEFT(modifier,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',modifier)+ PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',SUBSTRING(modifier,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',modifier),LEN(modifier)))-2)
Modifiedstring
FROM strs1

OUTPUT

/*------------------------

SELECT modifier,
LEFT(modifier,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',modifier)+ PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',SUBSTRING(modifier,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',modifier),LEN(modifier)))-2)
Modifiedstring
FROM strs1
------------------------*/
modifier                      Modifiedstring
----------------------------- -----------------
::22::                        ::22
:10:::                        :10

(2 row(s) affected)
```